# Inject collection of dependency with same base class in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a base Service class, and I have multiple different services in various different modules (produced by different teams) that inherit from this one. I want to call an "init" function, common in those service, at app startup. I don't want to call "init" on every services matching this type individually, because I am lazy.

In Java Spring, for example, I can simply have the whole collection injected, using the base class, with no other configuration than declaring those services injectables :

```
@Autowired
public void setServices(List<ProductService> productServices) { 
   for(ProductService service : productServices) {
      service.init();
   }
}
```

The direct similar way, of course, does not work.

```
constructor(private _productServices: ProductService[]) {
   // Does not work
   _productServices.forEach(x => x.init());
}
```

Is there a way to do this easily in Angular, or am I doomed to init all services manually ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not about laziness. There are multiple injectors in Angular, and thus all instances cannot be reached from a single place. More importantly, providers are lazily instantiated. It's unclear what init() is for. All initialization logic goes to class constructor. If there's a reason why this won't work, this should be reflected in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use injection tokens and multi providers to achieve what you are looking for with very little effort. With injection tokens you can even use an Interface to be injected.

Create an injection token:

```
export const INIT_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<BaseService>('BaseService');
```

Provide the services for the token using the multi flag:

```
{ provide: INIT_SERVICE, useClass: Derived1Service, multi: true }
```

Inject the token and initialise your services:

```
constructor(@Inject(INIT_SERVICE) initServices: BaseService[]) {
  initServices.forEach(service => service.init());
}
```

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bohg1o?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your anwser ! It has really helped us !

Answer (score 1):

Here's the plunker: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esdmif

You would need to provide all your services a little bit differently: given you have a base class (not interface, because interfaces do not exist in compiled JavaScript, so Angular is not able to find the service you want) and a couple of services that inherit from your base class.

Then you provide your services like following:

```
providers: [
    { provide: BaseService, useClass: AService, multi: true },
    { provide: BaseService, useClass: BService, multi: true },
    { provide: BaseService, useClass: CService, multi: true },
    { provide: BaseService, useClass: DService, multi: true }
]
```

The last `multi: true` parameter is required.

Then in your component you do:

```
constructor(@Inject(BaseService) private services: BaseService[]) {
}
```

There are some problems with this approach though:

1. You have to rewrite all your providers
2. You will not be able to inject your services like AService or BService
3. Since your services are distributed across different modules, they end up being in different injector

Comment: You can provide the services two times: once as BaseService and once as themselves. If you do so, you can inject them as AService, BService etc. What you cannot do on the other hand without using an injection token is to provide the BaseService itself.

Comment: @Markai It would be ok if your services are stateless. If you provide them one more time, they won't be singletons anymore

Comment: If you want them to be singletons, you can instantiate them and use `useValue` instead of `useClass` or even better write a factory and use `useFactory`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We have actually used the InjectionToken (the services are coming across multiples projects and multiple modules). The token is defined in the common librairies, and no one is actually forced to have a base class impl, only to provide the service with the token and respect the interface.